# Creating a Dedicated swap hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, swap

How can I create a dedicated hard drive to do "swap"on a ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use a partition or hdd for swap.

Just create a swap file using `dd` or `fallocate`.

Create a file of filled with zeros 1GB in this case:

```
 dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/swap.img bs=1M count=1024
```

**Preferred** method: use `fallocate` instead of `dd`

> **NOTE**: `fallocate` is much faster than `dd` because it quickly allocates blocks and mark them as uninitialized, no I/O to the blocks.

```
fallocate -l 1024M /mnt/swap.img
```

Format the file to create a swap device

```
mkswap /mnt/swap.img
```

Adding the swap to the running system:

```
swapon /mnt/swap.img
```

Make it permanent, edit `/etc/fstab` and add the following entry:

```
/mnt/swap.img  none  swap  sw  0 0
```

More information: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Comment: So @Terrywang, therefore if im creating a 4GB swap this is what is should look like                                                 sudo fallocate -l 4096m /mnt/4096MiB.swap
sudo chmod 600 /mnt/4096MiB.swap

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/4096MiB.swap bs=4M count=4096
sudo chmod 600 /mnt/4096MiB.swap

sudo mkswap /mnt/4096MiB.swap

sudo swapon /mnt/4096MiB.swap

gksudo gedit /etc/fstab

/mnt/4096MiB.swap  none  swap  sw  0 0

Comment: If you use `fallocate` to generate the swapfile, NO you don't need to du it using `dd` again, because they do the same thing, diff is `fallocate` is much faster. Otherwise the steps look good.

Comment: Well I was successful in creating the swap file, which i most say is running quite well. @terrywang