# Safe to create a swap partition using GParted?

Tags: installation, partitioning, gparted, swap

I went through [this forum post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/adding-swap-partition-after-system-installation), and found out that it is possible to install a swap partition after installation of the OS. I just wanted a guide as to how I should do it so as to have it done safely and neatly. Do I first free up space equal to 4000MB (my RAM size) from my Windows 8 installation drive and simply format the new free space to a linux-swap? How exactly do I then bind it to `/etc/fstab`? Do I use the terminal and run: `sudo update-initramfs -u` first, and then update the UUID using the commands shown in that thread? Also, can I include the previously "unallocated" and "unknown" partitions on my disk in the swap partition? Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look at this question: [Creating a Dedicated swap hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327186/creating-a-dedicated-swap-hard-drive)

You won't have to use a partition for swap, a swap file is totally fine, no performance penalty at all. See the abovementioned question, use `fallocate` or `dd` to create a swap file and `swapon` to use it. To make it survive reboots, add it to `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: I did all the stuff you recommended and I rebooted my computer. This is what I got:-

http://i39.tinypic.com/2iudohw.png

http://i40.tinypic.com/epg38p.png

The system seems to not be able to detect a swap. 

I figured I should have used the instructions suggested on the thread whose link I posted, especially identifying the UUID part, but now I am unsure as to how to redo it, because I didn't save the UUID which was shown on the terminal at the time of creation of swap.img. Do I just use swapoff and simply delete the file and start over? Please help.

Comment: Also, it seems as if my system has become a tad slower, perhaps it is not a good idea to have a 4GB swap file leaving only 11 GB free on a 20 GB partition? Just wondering.

Comment: You can `swapoff` the swap file and delete it, recreate it an use UUID, no problem. For swap file `/path/to/file` is OK, for swap partition UUID is recommended but `/dev/xxx` does the same job technically.

Comment: The screen shots showed you have no swap. Have you done `mkswap /mnt/swap.img` and then `swapon /mnt/swap.img`? Disk space is NOT the problem, slowness is mostly caused by swap in/out (check using `vmstat`), also adjust the `/proc/sys/vm/swappiness` value, set to 1 (don't set to 0 unless you know what you are doing).

Comment: Yes I followed the steps as you mentioned in the same exact order. I will retry it to check if I did anything wrong. Also /proc/sys/vm/swappiness reads 60. Is it a garbage value? Is it because there is no active swap present?

Comment: I realized I had made a horrible mistake. I used a # before adding the line in the fstab file which effectively made it a comment instead of a line with information. I have added the UUID in the file now and the swap is showing. 

i44.tinypic.com/f26dcl.png

However, after I restart the system, it doesn't show again and I have to use swapon to reactivate it. Is there something left to be done?

Comment: Cool, good to see it works;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread helpful, especially the last suggestion. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1796024 . I ran a boot repair which made the GRUB my default boot manager. That has made things a lot easier now. My swap gets turned automatically on, unlike previously when I had to use swapon to turn it on.