# GParted cannot identify swap partition on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, gparted, swap

I had a major system crash, after which I reinstalled Ubuntu 13.04. The problem was that I wasn't sure about creating a partition for swap using GParted because from what the online tutorials seemed to indicate, creation of a new partition would leave the original drive marked as "unallocated" with the remainder of free space (I might be wrong though, but I was hesitant).

Anyway, I couldn't boot either Windows or Ubuntu after I created a separate 4GB partition from my C drive on Windows. I ran a boot repair and fixed my Windows. Now the problem is that my system can detect swap at start up unlike here : [Safe to create a swap partition using GParted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339584/safe-to-create-a-swap-partition-using-gparted) , but GParted shows it to be an "unknown" partition.

[image]

Is there a way this can be fixed? Would it be okay to just right click and set it as swap, or are there some other changes to be made?

Comment: Did you encrypted home folder? This encrypts swap too, thats why its unknown. It's safer for data, but hibernation wont work. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safe to set it as swap. You should even be able to select it in Gparted, tell it to be swap and enable swap (Swapon) and go, no reboot etc needed.

Comment: http://i39.tinypic.com/20r2sr8.png I tried to format the drive to linux-swap after running sudo swapoff -a but above is what I got, and it still shows the partition as "unknown". I wonder if this happened because I created the volume in Windows? But the other volumes I created in Windows are showing alright.I don't understand what's wrong.